# (Doctrine-Ubuntu) Get error: doctrine-cli.php: command not found

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, doctrine

(Doctrine-Ubuntu) I run **$ doctrine-cli.php** command and get **doctrine-cli.php: command not found**.
P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in the command line if you just want to execute it:

```
chmod +x doctrine-cli.php
```

and optionally

```
cp doctrine-cli.php doctrine
```

this way you can do

```
./doctrine-cli.php [arguments]
```

and if you did the optional step you can do

```
./doctrine [arguments]
```

and if you don't want the ./ do this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/full/path/to/doctrine/folder
```

so now you can execute the `doctrine` command from any folder

What this does is adds the 'execute' permission to the file. If you have a proper shebang on the top of the file everything should execute fine (I imagine it does) and optionally adds the doctrine folder to your PATH so you can execute it from anywhere

Answer (score 3):

What's the exactly command you're executing? It should be something like this:

```
php doctrine-cli.php COMMAND
```

Also `php` should be available under `PATH` system variable but in Ubuntu (if you installed PHP by package installer) that's done by default.

Comment: Why should I add php before doctrine-cli.php COMMAND?
only in windows I should add php.exe before.

Comment: Thank you its working! like you write php doctrine-cli.php COMMAND